# Use Case based on Activity Diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

I wonder if anyone can assist me, I am trying to do a use case diagram from the activity diagram that I drew but I am not very good in use case diagram; can anyone guide me if what I did here is correct please.

You can see the diagrams at this link:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/activitydiagram.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/816/usecase.png/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background first.

Activity & Use Case Diagrams usually depict behaviour.  Activity Diagrams usually describe a process (or a linked sequence of activities).  Yours doesn't really do that.  That's OK - as long as the diagram works for you that's fine.

It's also normal to design an Activity Diagram as the process to realise a Use Case.  You're asking to go the other way.  Again, not conventional - but not impossible.

Use Cases are normally written as verb statements and describe actions a User would want to perform (e.g. "purchase book", "checkout").  Yours are nouns.

OK - so to your question.

Identifying the Use Cases involves asking the question: "What can Users do?".  Looking at your Activity Diagram, I'd guess the Use Cases would be something like:

- Take a Picture [with Camera]
- View Photos
- View Map
- View Current Location on Map

Each of those would be a Use Case.  There are probably others (what can a User do with Favourites?) but that should give you the idea.

hth.

Comment: Thanks for the input; well I agree perhaps my activity diagram isn't as it should be. Could you please show me or maybe if you have any example that I can refer to so I can change my activity diagram to the correct format please?

I have edit the case diagram as you suggest, can you please check if this seems okay?

Here is the link: 
http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/2001/usecase00.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The UC diagram is on the right lines.  Two comments: (1) `View Photos and Tree Details` sounds more like 2 different UCs - view photos & view trees.  It may not be though, because I don't know what 'trees' are and how they relate to photos.  As for example ADs: google for 'example activity diagram' and you'll get loads.

Comment: I have changed it here and give bit of details of what each cases does. Can you please see if Im doing it right or else please suggest me.

Thanks.
Link:

http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/1350/ucdiagram00.png

Comment: The trees here are related to the photo e.g Tree: Sweet Chestnuts, has it own data such as description, family name, species etc and on that screen we also button to view images of that particular tree in a different seasonal.

Comment: OK I'd say that looks about right now.  Maybe `View Tree Images` instead of simply `View Images` - assuming there aren't images of anything else.  But otherwise pretty good.

Comment: Thanks sfinnie, but is that all the data and relation in use case diagram? it doesn't seem enough info? :D 

Do we normally draw the UC diagram first then the Activity diagram?

Comment: Yes that's all in a UC diagram.  If you want to show data & relations use a class diagram. And yes, UC diagram usually comes before ADs.  You would typically draw 1 AD for each UC showing how it was realised.  Important to remember you don't have to draw anything - draw what you need to help you understand your problem.